# Wrong Max values returned by panda on reading a CSV Data File

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am attempting to calculate the maximum stock price and the latest date (today) on reading through two CSV Files - using the pandas max() function. However, the maximum value returned from one of the CSV Files 'Close/Last' column seems implausible.

```
# Read in Libaries
import pandas as pd

# Define Functions
def get_max_close(symbol):
    """ Return the max closing value for stock indicated by symbol."""

    df = pd.read_csv("Data\{}.csv".format(symbol)) # Read in data
    return df[' Close/Last'].max(), df['Date'].max() #compute Max and return the data to test_run


def test_run():
    """Function called by Test Run"""
    for symbol in ['AAPL','IBM']:
        print ("Max close")
        print (symbol, get_max_close(symbol))


# Main Program    
if __name__=="__main__":
    test_run()
```

The answer I get is:
Max close
AAPL (' $99.99', '12/31/2019')
Max close
IBM (' $215.8', '12/31/2019')

Clearly, the max values are higher than $99.99, and the date outdated.

I updated the pandas library too. However, the mistake still persists. Any help here would be appreciated.

The CSV File AAPL has data such as (example):
[AAPL.CSV File Data Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLPSH.png)

Comment: Can you paste your sample data frame and the expected result? Please follow [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-exampleto) get better response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Date values should be converted to date type using `pd.to_datetime()`. Currency are in string format, so you need to strip off the $ sign and convert them to float

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Close/Last'] = df['Close/Last'].apply(lambda x: x[1:]).astype(float)
print(df['Close/Last'].max())
print(df['Date'].max())
```

Output:

```
302.74
2020-03-13 00:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks, David. Used an easy string operation for the $ Sign removal and the output now looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

`' $99.99'` is a string, not a number. I don't know how Pandas' max method works on strings. In any case it would be safer to transform your data to proper float values before taking the maximum. The same issue could cause your problem with the dates. Pandas has a dedicated type for dates. The function `pd.to_datetime()` could be useful to convert your data accordingly. Then I would expect the max method to work as you intended.

Comment: Thanks, Arne for the help! Followed your steps and had the problem solved.